# Why the touchable area of a menu isn't correct in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, menu

I use a custom icon as a `label:` for a `Menu` which is to the right of each `ItemRow`. It looks like this:

```
HStack() {
    // Something here
    Spacer()
    Menu(content: {
        Button("Add", action: { add() ; isMenuOpened = false })
        Button("Delete", role: .destructive, action: { delete() ; isMenuOpened = false })
    }, label: {
        Image("options")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
    })
    .onTapGesture { isMenuOpened = true }
}
```

My problem is that the touchable area doesn't correspond to the entire icon but rather to the 3 small circles inside. I colored in orange one of the 2 following icons to show you their real shape/size:

[image: Custom icon for a menu]

First, it's really hard to open the menu with such a small touchable area. And second, I use this hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72454223/18547664 to avoid a problem with the other buttons in my `View` because of the `tap-to-close` which isn't automatic and so sometimes it shows me the `.overlay()` without opening the menu itself. It's really annoying!

I tried to solve this problem by using a `Rectangle` behind the icon in a `ZStack` or using `.contentShape(Rectangle())` but nothing works.

Do you have any ideas to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.contentShape(Rectangle())` as the last modifier helps a little bit but it's clearly not perfect.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Any idea how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Using `contentShape(Rectangle())` as the last modifier on the `Menu` instead of the `Image` helped a bit. And also using an invisible background color on the `HStack`.