# Context menu changes accent color

Tags: swiftui

I noticed that triggering a context menu changes the accent color from blue to grey.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @State var toggle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            // context menu
            List{
                ForEach((1...3), id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("Item \(i)")
                }
                .contextMenu {
                    Button(action: {
                    }){
                        Text("Copy")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: 200)
            
            // toggle
            Text("toggle: \(toggle.description)")
                .background(Color.accentColor)
            
            // buttons
            Button {
                toggle = !toggle
            } label: {
                Text("Send")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews2: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

This makes buttons look disabled, but they can still be pressed.

[image: gray accentColor]

[image: pressing button changes toggle value]

This is with iPadOS 16.5.1. In Xcode, a blur effect is used and outside clicks/presses are intercepted so the button can't be pressed.

[image: phone preview]

Am I supposed to add an [overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993631/swiftui-how-to-ignore-taps-on-background-when-menu-is-open) myself or is this a bug?